# dstatとfreeコマンドで見えるメモリの使用率の差異について

Tags: linux

dstatコマンドのusedとfreeコマンドのmemのusedに差異が見られます。（約5GB）

双方のコマンドで見るメモリの使用率になぜかのような違いが現れるのでしょうか。

OSはredhat7.3です。
dstatのバージョンは現在確認できる状態ではなく不明です。
情報が少なく申し訳ありませんがよろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

理由は、「計算式が異なるため」という事になります。

こちらの環境は以下の通りです。

```c
$ lsb_release -d
Description:    Ubuntu 19.04
$ uname -srm
Linux 5.0.0-15-generic x86_64
$ free --version
free from procps-ng 3.3.15
$ dstat --version
Dstat 0.7.3
```

**free**

[procps/proc/sysinfo.c:meminfo() function](https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps/blob/master/proc/sysinfo.c#L789)

/proc/meminfo から読み込んだ値から used memory を算出しています(dstat も同様)。

```c
kb_main_cached = kb_page_cache + kb_slab_reclaimable;
mem_used = kb_main_total - kb_main_free - kb_main_cached - kb_main_buffers;
```

kb_* 変数に対応する /proc/meminfo のフィールドは以下です。

```c
kb_page_cache: Cached
kb_slab_reclaimable: SReclaimable
kb_main_total: MemTotal
kb_main_free: MemFree
kb_main_buffers: Buffers
```

したがって、

```c
mem_used = MemTotal - MemFree - (Cached + SReclaimable) - Buffers
```

となります。

**dstat**

[dstat_mem.extract() method](https://github.com/dagwieers/dstat/blob/master/dstat#L1308)

```c
self.val['MemUsed'] = adv_val['MemTotal'] - self.val['MemFree'] - self.val['Buffers'] - self.val['Cached'] - adv_val['SReclaimable'] + adv_val['Shmem']
```

dstat では、

```c
mem_used = MemTotal - MemFree  - Buffers - Cached - SReclaimable + Shmem
```

となります。

結果として、Shmem(shared memory) の分だけ違いが出ることになります。

```c
$ free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          11829        2022        1384         114        8423        9731
Swap:          2047          24        2023

$ dstat --mem-adv
-------------advanced-memory-usage-------------
total  used  free  buff  cach dirty shmem  recl
11.6G 2136M 1384M  494M 7406M    0   114M  523M

## 2136 - 114 = 2022 MB
```

Comment: システム監視を行っていた時に、dstatで見たときのメモリ使用量が高く、freeで見た時のメモリ使用量が低く、この差が何であるのか、どちらの使用量を参考にするべきか分からず、上記の質問を行いました。shmemはtmpfsとして使用されているメモリ領域のため、キャッシュとして考え、freeの使用量を実際のメモリ使用量の参考にいたします。回答していただき、誠にありがとうございます。

Answer (score 0):

Oracle等がある場合、shmemは結構使います(SGAとして)。tmpfsとしてみれば確かにキャッシュとなりますが、
インスタンスがいる限り常に使用されている領域と考えれば、dtstatの方が実体を表していると思えますが、如何でしょうか？